# cache vs uncache memory access in embedded Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have an embedded target running embedded Linux and I want to calculate the following timings:

1) cache memory read/write timings
2) uncache memory read/write timings

Are there any standard tests in Linux to calculate the above timings?

I have written my own test that is:

```
void *mem_src  = (void*)malloc(MEM_SIZE);
void *mem_dest = (void*)malloc(MEM_SIZE);

clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &pre);
memcpy(mem_dest, mem_src, MEM_SIZE);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &post);

printf("time %ld\n",
        (SEC_TO_NSEC(post.tv_sec) + post.tv_nsec) -
        (SEC_TO_NSEC(pre.tv_sec) + pre.tv_nsec));
```

But the problem is that this test can only calculate the timings for cache memory access because the malloc in user space allocates the memory from cache region only.
I want the similar test for uncache memory region.

Answer (score 2):

First of all = your test measures memory bandwidth - if you want latency you need to make the accesses dependent (for e.g. traverse a linked list).

Second - you don't initialize your copied data so you'll get page faults within the times loop. Same problem described in here - [cpu cacheline and prefetch policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569146/cpu-cacheline-and-prefetch-policy/20569942#20569942)

For uncacheable requests - easiest option is to check if you compiler recognizes streaming stores/loads, they should behave very similarly to uncacheables (unless you're interested in measuring MMIO or similar special cases)

Comment: Yes, my target is to measure the bandwidth. I have properly initialized the copied data but not shown in above code to make it more readable. My target is just to calculate the uncache memory access time without caring amount MMIO or any other case. Is there any way to disable the cache subsystem in the embedded Linux without rebuilding the kernel (using shell commands etc)?

Comment: @user2463118 - Ok, the page faults might still be an issue, not sure if malloc takes care of that

Comment: On ARM (Cortex-A9) with Linux kernel at least back to 3.1, cache enable/disable is only compile time. You can disable L2C independently. Instruction and data cache can be disabled independently. With U-Boot, there are similar build-time controls, plus there is a console command that can enable/disable cache subsystem at run time. I have had good results in U-Boot, with small added code, to measure cache and memory bandwidth as you desire.

Comment: @JoeKul: Can you help me a little bit more. 

I am using ARM (Cortex-A9) with Linux kernel version:

**Linux localhost.localdomain 3.0.31+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Nov 25 17:09:21 EST 2012 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux**

What are the commands to enable/disable the caches in the system? 

It will be very helpful for me if you can share the piece of code to measure the bandwidth of cache and uncache memory or at least explain, how can I implement this test in u-boot?